# How can I access PHP array inside my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a very simple PHP array

```
$array = [];
$array['a'] = '1';
$array['b'] = '2';
$array['c'] = '3';
```

---

## PHP

If I `dd($array);` out I got

```
array:3 [▼
  "a" => "1"
  "b" => "2"
  "c" => "3"
]
```

If I decode `dd(json_encode($array));`, I got this

```
"{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}"
```

---

## JS

I want to be able to access this variable in my Javascript, So I've tried

---

## 1

**console.log($array);**

I got

> $array is not defined

---

## 2

I'm using Laravel. `{{ }} == echo`

**console.log('{{$array}}');**

I got

`500 Internal Error`

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /Users/bheng/Sites/portal/resources/views/cpe/index.blade.php)

---

## 3

**console.log('{{ json_encode($array)}}');**

I got

The page to load, but the data is very bad looking

`{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;b&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}`

---

## 4

**console.log(JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($array)}}'));**

I got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1

---

## 5

**console.log(JSON.parse('{{ json_decode($array)}}'));**

I got

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

---

## 6

**console.log('{{ json_decode($array)}}');**

I got

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

---

## GOAL

I just want to be able to access my array as Javascript Array or JSON in the Javascript.

Can someone please fill me in on this ?

Comment: What template language are you using for that `{{ ... }}` syntax? Blade, Smarty, something else? You should use something like `console.log({{ json_encode($array)}});` (without the quotes, as json_encode will add them where necessary), but you need the raw form, skipping the `htmlentities()` call your template engine seems to do

Comment: @rickdenhaan : blade.php

Comment: In that case, try `{!! json_encode($array) !!}`

Comment: Will do, I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @rickdenhaan : This `{!! json_encode($array) !!}` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer

Comment: I tried `console.log({!! json_encode($array) !!});` - now, I got `console.log({!! json_encode($array) !!});`

Comment: `echo "<script>var myData = JSON.parse(\"" . json_encode($array, TRUE) . "\");</script>";` then in Javascript: `<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) { alert(myData.a + '\n' + myData.b + '.......'); });</script>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Blade, `{{ $variable }}` will output an escaped version of the string, passed through `htmlentities()` to make it safe for use in HTML. You want an unescaped version. You can use `{!! $variable !!}` for that:

```
console.log({!! json_encode($array) !!});
```

You don't need to add quotes around it, `json_encode()` outputs a valid javascript object. It will add quotes where necessary, if you add them yourself you will get the JSON *string* in your javascript, instead of the JSON *object*.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you can use {!! !!} to skip entity escaping

```
console.log({!! json_encode($array) !!});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo it as json data and use it in javascript.

```
<?php
  $array = [];
  $array['a'] = '1';
  $array['b'] = '2';
  $array['c'] = '3';
?>
<script>var jsArr = <?=json_encode($array);?>;
alert(jsArr);</script>
```

EDIT because of clarification that you're using blade. Then it should be:

```
<?php
  $array = [];
  $array['a'] = '1';
  $array['b'] = '2';
  $array['c'] = '3';
?>
<script>var jsArr = {!! json_encode($array) !!};
alert(jsArr);</script>
```

{ ... } is an escaped version of your string. But you need the unescapt string. This can be achieved by using {!! ... !!}.

Comment: You sure, I think I tried that, let me try it again.

Comment: you tried it but used `JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($array)?>')`. But that's too much. JSON is a javascript object (notation). You don't have to decode it anothertime. Got it? If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand that PHP run on server side and javascript on client side, as PHP make the response you should print a script like this:

```
echo "<script>
var sheison = JSON.parse(".dd(json_encode($array)).");
console.log(sheison);
</script>";
```

I didn't test the code, is just the idea.